# How properly formatted do question titles have to be?

Tags: discussion, questions

I am not noticing any problem with the question titles on this SE, but for future reference I might as well ask this. How properly formatted do question titles have to be? Do they have to be like [Aviation](https://aviation.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1485/how-strict-do-we-need-to-be-about-making-sure-that-question-titles-reflect-the-a), where almost every title is questionised; [Meta SE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10647/how-do-i-write-a-good-title); or do/would we have our own question title policy?

Comment: I have a [meta.ELL post](http://meta.ell.stackexchange.com/questions/2630/how-can-i-write-a-better-title-for-my-ell-question) touching the same issue. I haven't seen bad titles on LL yet.

Answer (score 6):

## Policy: no. Guidelines/best practices: yes.

Question titles shouldn't be a necessary requirement of a question to be *on-topic*. That said, as a community, we should leave polite, respectful and helpful comments to users if necessary.

Comments like "*Welcome to Language Learning! Your title is a bit unclear, it should be about X*" are much more pleasant for new users and site veterans than overly pedantic on-topic requirements.

We can put together a *Best titles guidelines/best practices* reference Meta post together to link, like "*Welcome to Language Learning! Your title... See [How to write good titles](https://languagelearning.meta.stackexchange.com/) for more information!* "

Answer (score 2):

Titles need to be readable, and contain enough keywords relating to the question being asked, since when searching for past questions, or deciding whether to read a current one, it it not helpful when you see something like:

> What is the difference between these two methods?

I may have experience with one of them and could provide some assistance, but given the title I might just move on to the next question.